# Catching the unexpected in phone number entry

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

Right now I have the following:

```
 if(strlen($phbook_number)>6){
     $phbook_number=preg_replace("/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/", "$1-$2-$3", $phbook_number);
 }
```

My goal is that no matter how a user enters a phone number it will come out and be added to the DB as XXX-XXX-XXXX.

That above works till they break it with something like 123-3839282. I could always do a force check but I prefer to catch all and change to my format.

Is there an ideal way to go about this or do I need to code for every possible combination?

Comment: You could strip out all the non-digit characters first (`\D`), and then format the number.

Answer (score 3):

It will help if you  gave more possible cases. At least work with this ones:

1233839282

123-3839282

123-383-9282

+123-383-9282

+123 383 9282

```
$phbook_number=preg_replace("/^\+?(\d{3})(-| )?(\d{3})(-| )?(\d{4})$/", "$1-$3-$5", $phbook_number);
```

Basically you just need to put wathever simbol gets in the numbers in optional case "?"

PD:Sorry for my english...

UPDATE

```
preg_replace("/^[\+0-9\s\)\-\(]*(\d{3})[\s\)\-\(]*(\d{3})[\s\)\-\(]*(\d{4})[\s\)\-]*$/", "$1-$2-$3", $input_lines);
```

works now with spaces, "()" or else, the same logic, just using ranges now "[]" put whatever you think is goint to be in middle of the numbers inside each range

Comment: Nice. Heres another I forgot:
1 (XXX) XXX-XXXX I think the spaces are the big issue and throwing a 1 or country code in the mix

Comment: question, do you put in the regex all the numbers, or one by one?

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
// strip everything but the numbers
$phbook_number=preg_replace("/\D/", "", $phbook_number);
// remove the one country code so it can be formatted correctly
$phbook_number=substr($phbook_number, 1);
// add dashes to the number to be submitted for visual viewing
$phbook_number=preg_replace("/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/", "$1-$2-$3", $phbook_number);
```